# Theorem 9.41 Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[Rudin pp. 235-6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7XTN.png) I am having trouble following Rudin’s proof of theorem 9.41.  The first inequality is clear to me: for any $(x,y)$ sufficiently close to $(a,b)$, the difference in $D_{21}$ at these points can be made arbitrarily small.  However I do not understand how Rudin gets the next inequality.  The identity $\frac{\Delta(f,Q)}{hk}=hk(D_{21}f)(x,y)$ can only be said to apply for a point in the rectangle, $Q$, not for every $(x,y)$ in $Q$. Along the same line of reasoning it seems to me to be erroneous for Rudin to use the variable $b$ in (97), again, because the identity applies only to a specific $(x,y)$. Can anyone lend clarification to these issues?

**EDIT:** I believe that I have answered my own question and there is only one other problem that remains for me. **Final question:** Why, in equation (97), is there an $\leq$ sign instead of $<$ ?

My answer: Rudin uses theorem 9.40, which guarantees the existence of an $(x,y)$ in the interior of $Q$ that satisfies (95), to rewrite $D_{21}f(x,y)$ in terms of $a,b,h,k,$ and the function, $f$. He then applies limits twice in one inequality to get the desired derivatives.  Specifically,
$$|D_{21}f(x,y)-A|<\epsilon$$ for *all* $(x,y)$ in $Q$.  Now apply theorem 9.40 and hence write $$\bigg | \frac{\Delta(f,Q)}{hk}-A \bigg |=\bigg | \frac{1}{h} \cdot\frac{f(a+h,b+k)-f(a+h,b)-[f(a,b+k)-f(a,b)]}{k}-A \bigg |< \epsilon$$ for *some* $(x,y)$ in $Q$. Now take the limit of the first two and last two terms in the large numerator with $k$ approaching zero.  This gives equation (97).  This time it seems that we cannot take a limit because we are not told explicitly that $D_{12}$ exists. So instead Rudin says that equation (97) holds for all small $h$, and this is, incidentally, the derivative we want, $D_{12}$.

[Theorem 9.41, Rudin, PMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7XTN.png) and
[Theorem 9.40, Rudin, PMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNkSd.png)

Comment: Please give appropriate context for the problem by stating clearly for us what Theorem 9.41 says, what the proof says, and any unconventional definitions, notation or anything else we might need.

Comment: @D_S  I have added images for the two theorems cited in my question—theorems 9.40 and 9.41.  The images are links and are not shown in-line because this is my first post at stackexchange and I don’t yet have the requisite reputation to add the relevant images in-line.

Comment: If $a_n < b_n$ for all $n,$ in the limit $\lim a_n \leq \lim b_n$ can only be asserted. For example, $a_n = -1/n$ and $b_n = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

(97)

$$| \frac{(D_2 f)(a + h,b) - (D_2 f)(a,b)}{h}-A |≤ε.$$
Since $ ε$ was arbitrary, and since (97) holds for all sufficiently small $ h≠0$, it follows that
$$lim_{h→0}\;\frac{(D_2 f)(a + h,b) - (D_2\; f)(a,b)}{h}=A$$
That is,

$$(D_1 D_2  f)(a,b)=A$$
That is,

$$ (D_{12} f)(a,b) = A. $$

This gives (96).